# How to display terminal suggestions when command is not found (with a custom shell c program)

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I am trying to make a C program that mimics a linux shell/terminal using execvp(). I want my program to exactly output what displays in the terminal when a command is not found, suggesting some commands. How do I do that?

Currently, my program contains this:

```
if(execvp(argu[0], argu) < 0)
  printf("%s: Command not found\n", argu[0]);
  perror("");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Output:

```
bashtop: Command not found
No such file or directory
```

I want it to display this:

```
Command 'bashtop' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install bashtop
```

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: `printf("Command '%s' not found, but can be installed with:\n\nsudo snap install %s\n", argu[0], argu[0]);` and skip the `perror` line.

Comment: Is there a non hardcoded way?

Comment: You don't specify your OS and as far as I know there is not a command that returns the name of the default system package manager, maybe helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script